# Hotkey to instantly switch to a window of a specific application

Tags: 18.04, gnome, shortcut-keys

One can switch between running applications with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>. This requires visual feedback - you have to look at the screen and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> a certain number of times to cyclically select the needed application. This could be annoying if a lot of applications are running and you need to switch between them frequently.

So my question - is it ever possible (maybe some utilities exist) to 'bind' a specific keyboard shortcut to a specific application to instantly switch on its window without visual feedback?

For example in modern web browsers you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> to instantly switch on the first tab, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> to instantly switch on the second, etc. It would be wonderful to have similar functionality for application windows. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> and go to browser, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> and go to source code editor, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> to mail client, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> to messenger, etc

**EDIT**:
The solution is <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>, where N is <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, ...<kbd>9</kbd>. It may be required to set this config in `dconf` utility: `org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize'`

Comment: Duplicate question does not refer to binding your *own* keystroke for launching or switching applications, and is specific to Unity. Gnome Shell has this recently. Not sure if Ubuntu 18.04 already has this!

Comment: @vanadium question title is "how to instantly switch", not "how to setup my own keystroke to instantly switch". I've pinned duplicate label because solution described(`Super + N`) works for me in Ubuntu 18.04 with default GNOME shell